# Mips BMP File Geting the Pixel Value

Tags: assembly, mips, pixel, bmp

I am working on some image recognition project with MIPS assembly and trying to get the color value in a .bmp file. I have this piece of code that should give me the correct result in $v0 register but it keeps returning me 0x00000000 (which is black). I used Paint to paint source file in different colors but I keep getting  0x00000000. Can someone help me why this keep happening?

```
#only 24-bits 600x50 pixels BMP files are supported
.eqv BMP_FILE_SIZE 90122
.eqv BYTES_PER_ROW 1800

    .data
#space for the 600x50px 24-bits bmp image
.align 4
res:    .space 2
image:  .space BMP_FILE_SIZE

fname:  .asciiz "source.bmp"
    .text
main:
    jal read_bmp

    #get pixel color - $a0=x, $a1=y, result $v0=0x00RRGGBB
    li  $a0, 0      #x
    li  $a1, 0      #y
    jal     get_pixel

read_bmp:
#description: 
#   reads the contents of a bmp file into memory
#arguments:
#   none
#return value: none
    sub $sp, $sp, 4     #push $ra to the stack
    sw $ra,4($sp)
    sub $sp, $sp, 4     #push $s1
    sw $s1, 4($sp)
#open file
    li $v0, 13
        la $a0, fname       #file name 
        li $a1, 0       #flags: 0-read file
        li $a2, 0       #mode: ignored
        syscall
    move $s1, $v0      # save the file descriptor

#check for errors - if the file was opened
#...

#read file
    li $v0, 14
    move $a0, $s1
    la $a1, image
    li $a2, BMP_FILE_SIZE
    syscall

#close file
    li $v0, 16
    move $a0, $s1
        syscall

    lw $s1, 4($sp)      #restore (pop) $s1
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    lw $ra, 4($sp)      #restore (pop) $ra
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra

get_pixel:
#description: 
#   returns color of specified pixel
#arguments:
#   $a0 - x coordinate
#   $a1 - y coordinate - (0,0) - bottom left corner
#return value:
#   $v0 - 0RGB - pixel color

    sub $sp, $sp, 4     #push $ra to the stack
    sw $ra,4($sp)

    la $t1, image + 10  #adress of file offset to pixel array
    lw $t2, ($t1)       #file offset to pixel array in $t2
    la $t1, image       #adress of bitmap
    add $t2, $t1, $t2   #adress of pixel array in $t2

    #pixel address calculation
    mul $t1, $a1, BYTES_PER_ROW #t1= y*BYTES_PER_ROW
    move $t3, $a0       
    sll $a0, $a0, 1
    add $t3, $t3, $a0   #$t3= 3*x
    add $t1, $t1, $t3   #$t1 = 3x + y*BYTES_PER_ROW
    add $t2, $t2, $t1   #pixel address 

    #get color
    lbu $v0,($t2)       #load B
    lbu $t1,1($t2)      #load G
    sll $t1,$t1,8
    or $v0, $v0, $t1
    lbu $t1,2($t2)      #load R
        sll $t1,$t1,16
    or $v0, $v0, $t1

    lw $ra, 4($sp)      #restore (pop) $ra
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
```

Comment: The bmp format has a LOT of variations.  Without seeing which one Paint has chosen, it's hard to say just where the data will end up and how it will be formatted.  Perhaps you could post your bmp somewhere?  Also, my 'mips assembler' isn't good enough for me to be certain what offset you're using.  What offset into the file do you actually end up using to read bit 0? In particular, does `lw $t2, ($t1)` do what you expect?  Cuz I thought `lw` read a word, and the offset was stored as a dword.

Comment: A MIPS word is 32 bits, equivalent to an x86 DWORD.

Comment: @markgz - Well, there you go.  Still, the file and the offset he's using to read the pixel would probably make the problem clear.